# Bitbucket pre-branch-creation messages

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I often find that I would like to remind myself or my teammates to do some task the next time a branch is created.

Many times this task doesn't come in as a request to change something. For instance, maybe after the code was merged we realized that a package name didn't follow our coding standards, but the application still functioned properly.

This would be something that could be fixed the next time a functional change request was made.

I looked through the Bitbucket Server marketplace, but I didn't really see something that matched what I was looking for.

Does anyone know of something that might solve this? My team also uses Jira, but again, I was hoping to NOT create a Jira issue to track this, but I am open to suggestions.